# Deductibility of short-term foreign capital losses in India

Tags: income-tax, india, capital-gain, foreign-income

Since short-term capital gains on foreign stocks are taxed at the regular income (slab) rates in India, is one allowed in India to deduct short-term losses on foreign (relative to India) stocks from regular income?

Answer (score 1):

Foreign Capital losses cannot be offset against ordinary income. They can only be offset against foreign capital gains.

Comment: If the foreign capital loss exceeds the foreign capital gain in one year, can the unused loss be carried over to future tax years and used to offset foreign capital gains in future years, or is the excess lost forever?